# Find greatest in multiple groups across tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called Packages that contains some data and a related table that contains other information. It's set up like this:

```
Name|Version|Architecture|Date|id
```

And in a second table called Distribution I have this:

```
repo|id
```

The id's reference each other. I want to be able to get the newest (ordered by date) for a certain grouping. I want to group by Name, Architecture, and repo. The problem is I can't seem to get the normal greatest-n-in-group to work right because I have to go across tables. This is what I have so far

```
select
    p1.Name,
    p1.Version,
    p1.Arch,
    d1.repo,
    p1.Date
from Packages as p1
inner join Distribution as d1
    on p1.id = d1.id
inner join (
    select
        Name,
        Arch,
        repo,
        max(Date) as Date
    from Packages
    inner join Distribution
        on Packages.id = Distribution.id
    group by
        Name,
        Arch,
        repo
) as sq
    on p1.Name = sq.Name and p1.Arch = sq.Arch and d1.repo = sq.repo and p1.Date = sq.Date
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to group the repo correctly. It doesn't give me a unique repo.

EDIT: I want to get the newest version for each repo. So I have to get the max date in each repo, and then do the groups.

EDIT 2: I worked with one answer a bit to get this:

```
select p1.Name, p1.Version, p1.Arch, d1.repo, p1.Date
from Packages as p1 inner join
    Distribution as d1
    on p1.id = d1.id inner join (
        select Name, Arch, repo, max(Date) as Date
        from Packages inner join Distribution
            on Packages.id = Distribution.id
        group by Name, Arch, repo
    ) as sq
    on p1.Name = sq.Name and p1.Arch = sq.Arch and d1.repo = sq.repo and p1.Date = sq.Date
```

And that seems to be working for me.

Comment: I think the problem may be join condition giving multiple matches for some (name,arch,repo) combination when different versions have the same date. What's the type of date column? DATETIME or DATE?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to remove the `repo` from the max query:

```
select p1.Name, p1.Version, p1.Arch, d1.repo, p1.Date
from Packages p1 inner join
     Distribution d1
     on p1.id = d1.id inner join
     (select Name, Arch, max(Date) as Date
      from Packages
      group by Name, Arch
     ) sq
     on p1.Name = sq.Name and p1.Arch = sq.Arch and p1.Date = sq.Date;
```

EDIT:

If not all repos have a date, then you want to filter by distribution in the subquery.  However, you still don't want to put `repo` in the aggregation:

```
select p1.Name, p1.Version, p1.Arch, d1.repo, p1.Date
from Packages p1 inner join
     Distribution d1
     on p1.id = d1.id inner join
     (select Name, Arch, max(Date) as Date
      from Packages p join
           Distribution d
           on p.id = d.id
      group by Name, Arch
     ) sq
     on p1.Name = sq.Name and p1.Arch = sq.Arch and p1.Date = sq.Date;
```

Comment: Awesome! Looks like I didn't need to do that at all. I guess I was overthinking it.

Comment: This query won't show repos without newest versions at all. Are you sure this is what you wanted to get?

Comment: Hmm. You're right. It just happened to work for a specific query I did. EDIT: I want to be able to get the newest version in each repo. I'll edit my first post to clarify.

Comment: I did this except I also grouped by repo.

Comment: Personally, I dislike the use of eponymous aliases. It creates confusion (in my mind - MySQL's not bothered). Otherwise, top marks.